# Up-to-Date .NET Performance checklists

Tags: c#, .net, architecture

Searching about improving my .NET application's performance, I found the following articles on MSDN : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647606

Theses articles are outdated, and I am looking for more recent, maintained and valid checklists.

Does anyone have any up-to-date tips to improve a c# 4.0 Winform application ?

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a link reference site, it's a Question & Answer site.  Please, re-phrase your question about actually problems you are facing (including code).

Comment: Step one: first ensure that your application works. You don't want to optimize broken code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Theses articles are outdated, and I am looking for more recent, maintained and valid checklists.

There aren't any new "official" lists.  I believe this is because checklists are prone to abuse.  There are always exceptions, and checklists place the emphasis on the wrong things.  As .NET has proven itself quite a bit since the 1.1 days (which is when that checklist was designed), the need for these lists is less important.

Instead of focusing on checklists, its always better to just directly measure and adjust as needed.  Provided you've planned correctly (ie: make a good performance budget first), profiling will tell you *exactly* where to spend your energy and time.

Checklists tend to emphasize looking through all of your code, which is not an effective use of your optimization resources.

That being said, the lists you referenced are actually still relevent and basically valid.  Just realize that there are often better approaches now (ie: generics really change a lot of the guidance, as so much emphasis in those lists revolved around managing boxing and unboxing, etc).